# Zoom image with CSS3 with parent div have border radius overflow

Tags: html, css, hover, zooming

i try to use zoom image(scale CSS3) animation when mouse hover the image, but i have a problem with overflow during the animation, i want use tag `<img>` because i want put background color besides the image(have background transparency)

this is my problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
   <div class="divIMG">
      <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/14182-200.png" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.thumbnail div.divIMG {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #08456f;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbnail img {
  background-color: #c3d3de;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail div.divIMG:hover img {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j1rdv968/

anyone know a solution?

ps. sorry my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the transforming image inside of the `.divIMG` div by giving it a `position: relative;`, and a higher `z-index` than its child image.

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail div.divIMG {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
.thumbnail {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.thumbnail div.divIMG {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #08456f;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
  background-color: #c3d3de;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
}
.thumbnail div.divIMG:hover img {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="divIMG">
       <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/14182-200.png" alt="">
      </div>
     </div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1rdv968/1/)**

Comment: I had already used z-index, but without effect because i dont used position:relative, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! :)